Nashorn not recognized in Ant script with Amazon Corretto 21 and DITA-OT 4.2.3
I'm migrating our custom plugins to DITA OT 4.2.3, which requires a newer version of the JDK. We're using Amazon Corretto 21.0.3.9.1. We have one Ant build script that contains JavaScript. Since the JDK no longer contains the JavaScript engine, we're using Nashorn 15.4.
I copied the latest versions of the files (nashorn-core-15.4.jar, asm-9.7.jar, and asm-util-9.7.jar) into the lib folder of the plugin. In the Ant script, I added the following lines between <project> and the first <target>.
<path id="javax.classpath">
    <pathelement location="./lib/nashorn-core-15.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="./lib/asm-9.7.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="./lib/asm-util-9.7.jar"/>
</path>

I changed the <script> element as follows:
<script language="javascript" manager="javax" classpathref="javax.classpath">
      <![CDATA[var inputFolderInitVar = project.getProperty("inputFolderInit");
      var lastBackSlash = inputFolderInitVar.lastIndexOf("\\");
      project.setProperty("inputFolder", inputFolderInit.substring(0, lastBackSlash));]]>
</script>

But I'm still getting the "Unable to create javax script engine for javascript" error. Any idea what I'm missing?
FYI, I'm looking at regular expressions with ant-contrib or using Groovy script if the JavaScript option doesn't work. I would first like to see if we can get this working with JavaScript. Thanks.

Hard to tell from this much, but have you tried using ASM 7.3.1 instead? Nashorn uses ASM 7.3.1 as its declared dependency. And have you also tried adding all of asm, asm-commons, asm-tree, and asm-util? These are declared in the POM as dependencies.
Here's a little reproducer that works for me (with all libraries in a top-level directory):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ant-test" default="script-test" basedir=".">
  <target name="script-test">
    <path id="javax.classpath">
      <pathelement location="nashorn-core-15.4.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="asm-7.3.1.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="asm-commons-7.3.1.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="asm-tree-7.3.1.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="asm-util-7.3.1.jar"/>
    </path>
    <script language="javascript" manager="javax" classpathref="javax.classpath">
      <![CDATA[project.setProperty("foo", "bar");]]>
    </script>
    <echo message="${foo}"/>
  </target>
</project>

And here's my java and ant versions and the result of running it:
» java -version
openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu21.32+17-CA (build 21.0.2+13-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu21.32+17-CA (build 21.0.2+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
» ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.14 compiled on August 16 2023
» ant
Buildfile: /Users/attila/Documents/projects/ant-test/build.xml

script-test:
     [echo] bar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
» 

So all I can say it works for me on Java 21.0.2 and Ant 1.10.14.

Switching to ASM version 7.3.1 and adding the pathelement tags for all four asm jar files didn't work either. Do I need to add these to our JDK instead of trying to invoke them through our Ant script? Is there a way to add them using the JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS system variable? Thanks.

I just added a very small reproducer to my answer, but it works for me without an error. If I misspell the name of the JAR file, I'll get the "Unable to create javax script engine for javascript". If I misspell the method name for setProperty in the script, I get "project.setPxroperty is not a function" from within Nashorn. So… I can't reproduce it. I don't know anything about DITA-OT, if it does something weird with class loading it might cause it? If you can provide a full reproducer I will look into it.

Thank you for the update, Attila. I'm still having trouble. Is there a way I can send you this file directly?

A branch in a Git repo where you work on this? Or a new throwaway project on GitHub containing a reproducer? You can then share a link here. (And we can even open an issue in it to discuss further and collaborate.) Those would be my preferences. Also (and apologies if it goes without saying) please try to keep the reproducer to a minimum, I'm unlikely to be able to spend a lot of time comprehending it if it comes with a large context.

Thank you, Attila. I invited you as a collaborator for my repository so you can look at it.

I wound up using ant-contrib and propertyregex in place of JavaScript to extract the folder name. My specific problem is solved, but I'd like to keep this question open in case others need to get JavaScript to work using Nashorn. Thank you for your help.
